# How to assign compare operator of Sequelize in Op

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am sending the `filterType i.e. eq , lte , gte` etc in the query parameters and wants to check the `filterField` accordingly but when I put filterType like
`[Op.[filterType ]]` it gives error identifier expected . Can someone please help how I can assign it dynamically

```
let whereCondition = {
          [filterField]: {
            [Op.[filterType]]: filterValue
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [] around the operator. Please read [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html)

example:

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    authorId: {
      [Op.or]: [12, 13]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @OP wants the operator to be a parameter, not hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax problem:

```
        [Op.[filterType]]: filterValue
```

Should be:

```
        [Op[filterType]]: filterValue
```

Lose the `.`

Comment: I tried this one already but this gives error

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ readonly adjacent: unique symbol; readonly all: unique symbol; readonly and: unique symbol; readonly any: unique symbol; readonly between: unique symbol; readonly col: unique symbol; ... 31 more ...; readonly values: unique symbol; }'.`

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code?   The following works fine for me: `let myOp = 'gt';
 Meeting.findAll({ where: {  'id' : { [Op[myOp]] : 1 }} })`.   It compiles to SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE meeting.id > 1

Comment: Error is resolved by initialising the filterType field as
`filterType  : keyof typeof Op`